# Print all lines which not containing punctuation

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want a regex pattern which can print all lines which not containing punctuation :

**Input :**

```
.This is line 1
This is ! line 2
This is line (3)
This is line 4
```

**Output:** ( should be)

```
This is line 4
```

**What I've tried so far :**

```
grep '[^[:punct:]]' file.txt
```

But it shows all characters which is not punctuation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `grep` prints all lines containing non-punctuation characters. That's not the same as printing all lines that do not contain punctuation characters.

For the latter, you want the `-v` switch (print lines that don't match the pattern):

```
grep -v '[[:punct:]]' file.txt
```

If, for some reason you don't want to use the `-v` switch, you must make sure that the whole line consists of non-punctuation characters:

```
grep '^[^[:punct:]]\+$' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 thanks. Is there any way without using `-v` switch ?

Comment: @HamedKamrava Yes. Please see my edit.

Comment: @HamedKamrava Out of curiosity: why would you want to avoid `-v`?

Comment: I don't avoid `-v` just want to know more :)

Comment: @HamedKamrava Please don't forget to mark this answer 'Accepted' if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In sed you can do something like:

`sed '/[[:punct:]]/!d'`

In awk you can do:

`awk '!/[[:punct:]]/'`

Answer (score 1):

A `Perl` ones:

```
perl -nle 'print unless /\p{XPosixPunct}/' file
```

This will match **-!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~** which unicode consider Punctutation and Symbols.

or:

```
perl -nle 'print unless /\p{Punct}/' file
```

`\p{Punct}` only matches **-!"#%&'()*,./:;?@[\]_{}**, missing **$+<=>^`|~** which unicode consider Symbols.

`perl` by default use POSIX locale. If you don't use `perl`, you should all so set `LC_ALL=POSIX`, because different locale can have different punctuation characters like `SAA C` has `¢`.